# Connecting to FileZilla FTP Server on XAMPP localhost with Dreamweaver

Tags: ftp, filezilla, xampp, dreamweaver

I am running XAMPP 1.7.4. I've installed the FileZilla FTP server and I'm running it as a service. I created a user and when I connect as that user with the FileZilla client, I have no trouble connecting.

However, in Dreamweaver CS5 when I create a site using the Manage Sites dialog and go to configure its FTP settings, I get a message that reads

```
An FTP error occurred - cannot make connection to host.
```

and goes on to list some possible causes and solutions.

I have tried setting the connection as passive to no avail.

I understand that it is not necessary to use FTP when I am editing the site locally, but it is for a Dreamweaver class I am teaching and I want my students to learn to use Dreamweaver's FTP tools.

How can I make my localhost FTP connection work in Dreamweaver?

Comment: If this is on a Windows machine, have you checked the firewall settings to see if they allow inbound connections to FTP?

Answer (score -1):

It can't be the firewall if Filezilla is connecting fine.  The port must be open for any FTP connection.   But just in case i'm wrong, turn off the firewall and see if you get a connection.

Are you trying to connect via a hostname, IP or localhost, 127.0.0.1?

I don't have Dreamweaver available at the moment, but later today i can try a test.   I have CS7 and a local server running a Bitnami WAMP stack with Filezilla Server.